# magento2 Mass Action to Custom Page in Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, action

I have added a custom option to the magento2 admin order action-dropdown in `view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`. Then  I created a custom method `Controller/Adminhtml/Order/MassDoSomething.php`, where I can do something with the selected orders in the method `protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)`; Thats works.

But is to possible to show a custom page "intemediate page" where I can show the selected orders? Or do I have to create a new admin page (like https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html) and redirect the users from the Mass Action to this page?

How can I create a custom page with the selected orders?